# Writing API code in Python, Barcode lookup, "argument of type 'int' is not iterable"

Tags: python, json

I'm writing a code to pull from a UPC/barcode database API, and I'm trying to make it so if you find one thing in the pulled JSON data ('"total": 1'), then print out the name of the item. I get the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/thomasceluzza/Documents/UPC API Grabber/api.py", line 13, in <module> 
    if '1' in importedJSON['total']:
    TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Which comes from the full code

```
    import urllib2
    import json
    import sys

    while '1' == '1':
        apikey = 'c2c33e74ea9ee432fd1cdbf546a3132c'
        upc = raw_input("Scan your barcode: ")
        url = 'https://api.upcitemdb.com/prod/trial/lookup?upc=' + str(upc)
        json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)

    importedJSON = json.load(json_obj)
    if importedJSON['code'] == 'OK':
        if '1' in importedJSON['total']:
            print ' '
            print 'The product you scanned is ',
            for name in importedJSON['items']:
                sys.stdout.write(name['title'])
            print ' '
            print ' '
        else:
            print ' '
            print 'NOT IN DATABASE'
            print ' '
    else:
        print ' '
        print 'Invalid UPC/EAN code. Please scan again.'
        print ' '
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `total` stores an `int` value, not `str`. So presumably you want to test:

```
if importedJSON['total'] == 1:
```

or to test for any non-zero `total`:

```
if importedJSON['total']:
```

Your `json.load` call performed type conversion, and you're acting like it didn't. Even if it hadn't though, `if '1' in importedJSON['total']:` would only make sense if `total` was a `list`, or a stringified number and for some reason `"1"` and `"21"` were acceptable, but `"2"` was not. `in` is for containment checks after all, not equality checking.